# .htaccess rewrite

Tags: url-rewrite, .htaccess

I have this url which is working:
http://www.example.com/linea?linea=7

It gives me all the products of the category "linea" filtered by the custom parameter "linea", in this case the value is equal to `7`

I want to make it more readable so I put this rewrite in the `.htaccess` file but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^bimbo(/.*)?$ index.php/linea?linea=7 [L,QSA]
```

It should be called when I type in the url:
http://www.example.com/bimbo

Anybody knows why?

---

No idea why, but it works fine if rewrites are on proxy `[P]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Magento platform. You should ask this question at http://serverfault.com. There, you'll have better chances of finding the solution.

Comment: I think it is related because this rewrite is working on a plain system while with Magento it is not

Comment: I take my vote back then. You should add this detail to the question, otherwise someone else will do the same.

Comment: why do you add index.php/ in your target url?

Comment: I tried without index.php as well but still not working

Comment: If it's not necessary to do it via htaccess file, you can add this rule via "URL Rewrite Management" feature from admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)linea=7($|&)
RewriteRule ^linea$ /bimbo? [L,R=301]
```